# Stop users from removing subdocuments in Autoform

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

What should happen is a user can add a subdocument with the big [+] button, but cannot remove it without a prompt.  Basically just deleting the [-] button.  How do I do that?  Can I do that?

If it can't be done I have other solutions to my problem, but that seems to defeat the purpose of the using this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the [-] button.

For add new document you have to write a following code in the events.

```
Template.TemplateName.events({  
    "click .autoform-add-item" :function(){
       //This allow to remove the current [-] button as well.
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.autoform-remove-item').remove();
        });
    },
});
```

For add edit document you have to add the remove [-] button code in onRendered block as well, like :

```
Template.TemplateName.onRendered(function () {
    $('.autoform-remove-item').remove();
});
```

@Note :: Please make sure then you have "autoform-add-item" class on [+] button and "autoform-remove-item" on [-] button. You can check these classes using inspect element.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for an Autoform native solution but I guess it's not something Aldeed was looking to support at this stage.